# Can a Flask (or other SSR) app receive client-side events without JS?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am making an app (as an educational exercise) that is purely rendered server-side and uses no client-side JS whatsoever. A key part of the app is that the server needs to be able to intercept *client-side* events - keyboard input, click, drag, cursor location, etc.

A rough sketch would be something like this -

`app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
counter = 0

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def hello_world():
    global counter
    if request.method == "POST":
        counter += 1
    return render_template("index.html", counter=counter)
```

`templates/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flask SSR demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Flask no JS app</h1>
    <p>You have clicked {{ counter }} times!</p>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        fetch("/", {
            "method": "POST",
        });
    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, this method requires JS to register event listeners. Is there any way to do it purely from the server-side?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Well, for this particular example it may be possible by e.g. placing a fully transparent image in an `a` tag over the whole document.